# How to use BindingList of object of different classes sharing same interface as datasource of datagridview

Tags: c#, interface, datagridview, datasource

I have many classes sharing a interface.I have also created a BindingList consist of objects created from these classes.

Now i want to use this binding list as a Datasource for a Datagridview.

would this work?can please someone give me some example.

Comment: It could work - but you have to be more specific in your question. Please post some code.

Comment: My main aim is to somehow show object of different classes in datagridview. If all the object belongs to same class , it is very easy , just add them to a binding list and set that bindinglist as datasource for datagridview.But Now i have many classes. These classes

Comment: Still need more info - do you want to display all of the properties from all of the types of objects (display blanks for the properties that don't exist on individual rows / objects)?

Comment: these all classes have exactly same number of properties and i want to show them all.For example All classes has three properties (name,age,sex) and there is no properties other then that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wait - can you just create a BindingList of IMyInterface ?

```
myList = new List<IMyInterface>();

myList.Add(new Foo());
myList.Add(new Bar());

myDataGridView.DataSource = myList;
```

Foo and Bar implement IMyInterface